React Native Custom Drawer Content Not Rendering
Nothing in my custom drawer content is rendered in my app after being passed into my drawer navigator. (The drawer is literally just a white screen).
Here is my AppNavigator.tsx:
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator()
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator()

const StackNavigator = () => (
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing Page" screenOptions={ {headerShown: false} }>
        <Stack.Screen name="Landing Page" component={LandingPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Contact Us" component={ContactUsPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="FAQ" component={FAQ} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Products" component={Products} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Registration Page" component={RegistrationPage} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Team" component={Team} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Logged In Home Page" component={LoggedInHomePage}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Values" component={values} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Relief Page" component={ReliefPage} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);

const DrawerNavigator = () => (
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Landing Page" drawerContent={CustomDrawerContent} screenOptions={ {headerShown: false}}>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Landing Page" component={StackNavigator}/>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={login} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Contact Us" component={ContactUsPage} /> 
        <Drawer.Screen name="FAQ" component={FAQ} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Products" component={Products} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Registration Page" component={RegistrationPage} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Team" component={Team} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Values" component={values} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Relief Page" component={ReliefPage} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>

);

const AppNavigator = () => (
    <DrawerNavigator/>
)

export default AppNavigator

And here is the custom drawer content in "CustomDrawer.tsx"
import { DrawerContentComponentProps, DrawerContentScrollView, DrawerItemList } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { Text } from "react-native-svg";
import { View } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import styles from '@/styles/landingPage.styles';


export default function CustomDrawerContent(props: DrawerContentComponentProps) {

    return(
        <View>
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#696969'}}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.heroButton} activeOpacity={0.5}>
                    <Text>Join the Tribe</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}

